# Using value fetched from API in ngStyle in Angular

Tags: angular

I searched for it but I wasn't able to find a solution so I am putting it here.

**What I want?**

=> I want to apply specific width (fetched from API call) to a particular *div*.

**What  I am doing:**

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': apiData?.widthPercent === null ? '0%' : 'apiData?.widthPercent%'}"></div>
```

What I think is that the problem is with **'apiData?.widthPercent%'** but am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: `'apiData?.widthPercent%'` is a string. What you want is it being a variable. Try `apiData?.widthPercent + '%'`

Comment: Hi @JanS, it worked like the charm, thanks.
Please put it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else`-case is currently just a string. What you want to use is a variable that is appended by `%`.

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': apiData?.widthPercent === null ? '0%' : apiData?.widthPercent + '%'}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks again @JanS. :)